# Syntax Hidden Parameter Plugin in groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, hidden-field

I have an issue with the writing pipelines with a hidden parameter.

I installed Hidden Parameter Plugin to my Jenkins and I would like to hide some parameters.
Actually I understand how to use StringParameterDefinition, but I can not hide this parameter

`[$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'N/A', description: 'some text', name: 'variable', hidden: true]`

After installation Hidden Parameter Plugin I can see "Hidden Parameter" during adding a parameter, but I have the groovy file, which is downloaded on each build, that's why I would like to write it in the groovy pipe.

Could you please help me with syntax for hidden parameter?